# Fibers of projection homemorphic to affine line $\mathbb{A}_{k(s)}^1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

the problem I am dealing with is part of a three step problem in order to show how the affine line $\mathbb{A}_R^1 = Spec(R[t])$ for a PID $R$ looks like. The problem has been dealt with a lot here on stack exchange, but my question is related to a specific part of the solution. Namely, let $\pi:\mathbb{A}_R^1\rightarrow Spec(R)$ be the projection associated to the canonical injection $R\rightarrow R[t]$.

Given a point $s\in Spec(R)$, the fiber $\pi^{-1}(s)$ is canonically homeomorphic to the affine line $\mathbb{A}_{k(s)}^1$, where $k(s)$ is the residue field of $s$.

So I guess this is a fairly trivial fact but I just don't see it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: By definition $\Bbb A^n_{k(s)} = \Bbb A^n \times_{\Bbb Z} \text{Spec} \;k(s)$. Also $\Bbb A^n_{R} = \Bbb A^n \times_{\Bbb Z} \text{Spec} \; R$. From here it is not hard to see that the statement holds.

Comment: For a prime ideal $I \subset R[t]$ then $\pi(I) = I \cap R$, since $s$ is maximal $s \subset I \implies s \subset I \cap R \implies s = I \cap R$ so $\pi^{-1}(s)$ is the prime ideals of $R[t]$ containing $s$ quite the same as the prime ideals of $R/s[t]$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since $s$ is maximal the residue field of $s$ is literally the same as $R/s$. I think this confused me a bit,